# ubuntu backup-manager Permission denied

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, backupmanager

I've recently installed backup manager onto my ubuntu machine to have automated backup going. The problem is when I go to set up the automatization using this code -

[image: code]

it comes us up saying this "bash: /etc/backup-manager.sh: Permission denied"

I do not understand this error. I've tried change the user who read/writes to someone other than root and that didn't work. I tried changed the chmod number from 770 to 700 and still didn't work.

[image]

any info on this is welcome. Thank you to those who help :) 
those wondering I am using this tutorial giving to me by the host. https://documentation.online.net/en/dedicated-server/tutorials/backup/configure-backup/start

I'm using the desktop version of ubuntu 16 incase that is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sudo doesn't do what you want in this case. What happens is that the shell evaluates the redirection and attempts to open the `/etc/backup-manager.sh` for you before the `sudo cat` even gets started. That fails because the shell still runs as you unprivileged user. You have to say `sudo -i` to open a new root shell, execute the commands and exit again.
Alternatively you could try `sudo nano /etc/backup-manager.sh` and paste the contents there. This would work because the editor is run as root and does the file opening itself when you save.

Comment: Yes! Thank you I've been trying to get this to work for ages. I'm a new user of this OS but I'm finding it fun working out how to do things for this though I needed a little extra help :P Thank you for teaching me this and solving my issue!